# Python: Why is my `for` loop being skipped?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have this code:

```
for i in range(40):
    print("execution:", i, end="    ")
    if player_y - i >= 0:
        if roomMap[player_y - i][player_x] == 1:
            roomMap[player_y - i][player_x] = 3
```

The variables `player_x`, `player_y` and the list `roomMap` are already defined, but it does nothing and I am unsure what's happening.

Comment: Check the conditions are correct.

Comment: This loop *must* run, and that print *must* happen. If it isn't, this loop is never being reached in the first place, so the problem is caused by code that you haven't included here.

Comment: Agreed. As mentioned by @Carcigenicate, there is most likely something happening before that chunk of code. What are `player_y` and `player_x` values before the for loop?

Comment: The rest of my code is over 200 lines, but I have tested it before without it and it worked. player_x  is 5, player_y is 2, and roomMap is a 40x40 square of zeros from loops in loops, with ones around the edge

Comment: The path that leads to this code must not be executing. At the very least, we'd need to see what conditions lead to this loop being reached, and what data is involved in those conditions.

Comment: If you are not seeing `"execution"` being printed, then there is something happening before the for loop that is not reaching that part of the code. If it worked at one point, it will have to be something introduced.

Comment: That means it was something wrong in the snippet.

Comment: Or you are looking in the wrong place for output from the script. Do you see output from any other `print` calls elsewhere in the script?

Comment: I see other prints from the createrocks() functio, where it prints random x and y positions, and sets some variables to that then prints them.

Comment: Correction: createrocks() function. Just noticed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple reasons why your loop would not be running

- You had a conditional statement (if) surrounding it and the code happened not to run through that branch
- You maybe had a return statement before getting into that loop and your code terminated

Steps you can take to resolve that:

- Try to use the debugger and see if the code goes inside this loop
- You can also use "print()" statements to caveman debug it, maybe use `print("I am inside the loop")` see if you can print that in the console from inside the loop.

Comment: From the print Idea, I got: `execution: 0    In loop
execution: 1    In loop
execution: 2    In loop`
but nothing else (except the rock's prints)

Comment: Is there a conditional statement surrounding it then?

Comment: I changed my code to: `for i in range(40):
    print("execution:", i, end="    ")
    if player_y - i >= 0:
        print("In loop")
        if roomMap[player_y - i][player_x] == 1:
            print("In loop", i)
            roomMap[player_y - i][player_x] = 3
    else:
        print(player_y - i)` and it outputs: `execution: 0    In loop
execution: 1    In loop
execution: 2    In loop
execution: 3    -1`

Comment: and so on...(15 charecters)

Comment: Can you at least show me the console prints? To determine where exactly it goes?